# Translating a db into different languages

Tags: php, mysql, database, gettext

I'm using *gettext* for the translation of my webpage. I already have almost of my webpage translated in four languages (Spanish, English, French and Portuguese). I only have translated the things in my php files.

What I want is to also translate the things in my db, for example, some texts I have stored there. How can I do it?
I thought of replacing variable that takes the value from the db with a `echo _($var);`, but I don't think this would be a really option.

So, would you reccomend me another way to do that, or I have to translate it using gettext?
Thanks!

Comment: I wrote [a blog post about this some time ago](http://rwec.co.uk/q/atom-i18n-1). My solution is postgres-specific (or the implementation is, anyway) but I list some of the other solutions I've come across elsewhere.

Comment: @IMSoP Okay thanks! I will have a look at it! :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your database, however one solution is to translate db values in to appropriate languages and create table with language key so that table gets normalized and depending upon language selection you can refer to that table.

Comment: Yep, I thought about that! If I can't find anything better, I'll do this!

Answer (score 0):

One implementation that works well for me is keeping all the UI code on the UI side.  That means putting the items to be translated into your JavaScript file so that your Grunt task will extract it from the JavaScript files.  Ruben Vermeersch talks about this in his post [a Marking strings in JavaScript code as translatable](http://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/annotate-js/).  Here is an example of the code that I used in a test project to demonstrate this idea.

```
angular.module('Test')
    .controller(['gettext', function(gettext) {
        //  Arrays Required for Translation Grunt Task (Do Not Remove)
        var productNames = [
            gettext("Access"),
            gettext("Database Compare"),
            gettext("Excel"),
            gettext("Lync"),
            gettext("OneNote"),
            gettext("Outlook"),
            gettext("PowerPoint"),
            gettext("Publisher"),
            gettext("Visio"),
            gettext("Word")
        ];
    }]);
```

After you annotate your JavaScript in such a manner, you run the ‘grunt extract’ task again, you should see these values in your *.pot file.

Now your ready to do your translation and compile it back into your translations JavaScript file.  When the UI now gets "Access" for example from the back-end, it will will know how to translate this to "Acceso" if the Spanish language is selected for example.

I talk about this in more depth in my blog post [a Localization With Angular-GetText](http://outofmemoryexception.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/localization-with-angular-gettext/).  If you still have questions, please refer to that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and we decided to do all translation on the front end with angular-gettext.

Basically we extracted all the strings we needed from my DB and put them into an html file. Then created a `postTranslate` filter that runs on the interpolated value.

For more details look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26346778/269608).